# How can I hash something using MD5 or SHA3_512 algorithm from default System.Security.Cryptography namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, system.security

I tried to use HashAlgorithm.Create() to initialize my hashing algorithm, but I get PlatformNotSupportedException when I try to run it.

I also tried just initializing HashAlgorithms with `new MD5();` but it obviously didn't work since MD5 and other HashAlgorithms are `abstract` classes.

Documentation states that HashAlgorithm.Create() is obsolete and won't work anymore, but all code samples still use this method with no alternative provided.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.create?view=net-8.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/compatibility/unsupported-apis

I would expect line
`private readonly SHA3_512 _sha3_512 = SHA3_512.Create();`
to not throw PlatformNotSupportedException, especially since SHA3_512 class was added in .NET 8

Comment: The [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha512managed?view=net-8.0#examples) I see uses `SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed(); result = shaM.ComputeHash(data);`, not `Create()`...

Comment: Generally, it's good form to use _ArgorithmName_`.Create` (for example, `SHA3_512.Create()`. That should get you an implementation for the platform you are running on. Here's an example for SHA256: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=net-8.0

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious, but you can use [rfc2898derivebytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.getbytes?view=net-8.0) to perform this operation.

```
byte[] CreateHash(string clearText, byte[] salt, int workFactor, int hashSize)
{
    var hasher = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes
    (
        password: clearText,
        salt: salt,
        iterations: workFactor,
        hashAlgorithm: HashAlgorithmName.SHA512
    );
    return hasher.GetBytes(hashSize);
}
```